# Re-ordering primary key column that is used as a sorting clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I'm working with a legacy software and for numerous reasons I cannot touch the database schema.
I have a database with ID column that serves as primary key and also as a sorting clause ("ORDER BY ID"). I need a way to "re-order" my list.

For instance, if I have:

```
ID | Data...
------------
1  | A
10 | B
17 | C
18 | D
```

Given the ID what would be the best way to move the record "up" or "down".
So that: C -> "up", would change C's ID to be between A and B; and so on.

Everything is in MySQL if that helps.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: your expected result result ?

Comment: If "c->down" - then why between `A` and `B`? I think it should be after `D`. Or is it about `ID`? (i.e. "down" = "descrease ID on one position")

Comment: Are there any foreign keys referencing "ID"? Do updates cascade?

Comment: Also, what if `id` isn't always in ascending order? I.e. `A->1`, `B->3`, `C->2`, `D->4` and we want to move `D` "down" ?

Comment: @echo_Me After moving C "up", I'd expect the ORDER BY ID return sorted list: A C B D

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' there are no foreign keys or cascades

Comment: @AlmaDo Sorry, was a typo, I meant to say "up". Corrected. But it doesn't really matter what we reference as "up" or "down" as long as it's consistent.

Comment: @rexem: And how many such up's and down's in a single selection?

Comment: *"So that: C -> "up", would change C's ID to be between A and B; and so on."* There's no guarantee that there will be a hole between A and B. That means you might have to renumber an arbitrarily large subset of the whole table. If MySQL supported deferrable constraints, you could just swap ID numbers in a single transaction. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For the sample data like in your question, the result can be shown in a simple way, but if the `data` values differ further, and you want them too shuffle and place at different positions, then you have to do it at your application level or in a stored procedure.

For small amount of data as in your example and if data `'A'` is not repeating, the solution can be:

```
mysql> select * from
    -> (
    ->             select  1 as id, 'A' as data
    ->   UNION ALL select 18,       'D'
    ->   UNION ALL select 17,       'C'
    ->   UNION ALL select 10,       'B'
    -> ) table_name
    -> order by field( data, 'C', 'A' ) desc, data;
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
| 17 | C    |
| 10 | B    |
| 18 | D    |
+----+------+
```

If `'A'` repeats several times, the same query results as below. But check that row with data `'C'` is placed just after all `'A'` rows are ordered.

```
mysql> select * from
    -> (
    ->             select 26 as id, 'X' as data
    ->   UNION ALL select  1,       'A'
    ->   UNION ALL select 18,       'D'
    ->   UNION ALL select 17,       'C'
    ->   UNION ALL select 10,       'B'
    ->   UNION ALL select 15,       'A'
    ->   UNION ALL select 25,       'C'
    -> ) table_name
    -> order by field( data, 'C', 'A' ) desc, data;
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
| 15 | A    |
| 17 | C    |
| 25 | C    |
| 10 | B    |
| 18 | D    |
| 26 | X    |
+----+------+
```